# 「Drive.Files.update」で404エラーが発生

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-sdk

GASにて共有ドライブ（チームドライブ）内でファイルの移動を行うため、
Drive.Files.updateを使って試しています。
下記、コードで実行していますが404エラーが発生しており、どこが間違っているのか分かりません。
認証設定が足りないのでしょうか？
なお、APIs Explorerで試してみると実行できます。

```
function moveFile() {
  var fileId = "1-U2N35iiwcz_Q8KXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var sourceFolderId = "1gAF-FfwQ0nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var destFolderId = "19wJOjV7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  Drive.Files.update({"fileId" : fileId ,"addParents": destFolderId, "removeParents" : sourceFolderId, "supportsAllDrives" : true},
    function (err, file) {
      if (err) {
        Logger.log(err + "file:" + file);
        // Handle error
      } else {
        // File moved.
      }
    });
};
```

※IDはマスキングしています

Comment: 問題が解決した場合には質問文に含めてしまうのではなく、ぜひ「自己回答」として個別に投稿してみてください。スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答も歓迎です。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

今更ですが、自己解決したら「自己回答」として投稿しろとのアドバイス？が来ていたので
こちらを更新しておきます。

GASとJavascriptの実行を混同していたようで、
パラメータの設定の仕方が悪かったようです。

```
Drive.Files.update(
   null     // File resourceの指定はなしで問題ない
  ,fileId   // File Id
  ,null     // mediaファイルじゃないので指定なし
  ,{'addParents'        : destFolderId
   ,'removeParents'     : sourceFolderId
   ,'supportsAllDrives' : true // 非推奨になっていたが指定しないのNot Foundになる
   } // Optional query parametersで指定
);
```